# What is the duration of a spell from a magic item?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

In my case I have a [Celestial Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/celestial-armor) (CL5) and a [Celestial Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-shields/celestial-shield) (CL7)
The armor lets me [fly](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly) once per day (as the spell) and the shield gifes me [feather fall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/feather-fall) once per day and because I have both I could use [overland flight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/overland-flight) rather than fly.
Do I use my caster level to determine the duration of those spells or the CL of the magic-items? [fly](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly)=5 min., [feather fall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/feather-fall)=7 rounds, [overland flight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/overland-flight)=5 hours or do I use my own or the highest of the two?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use the item’s caster level. The only exception to this is for staves, which you use your stats if they are higher.

Answer (score 8):

For determining duration, as well as any other CL dependent variables such as DC for dispel magic, you'll use the Caster Level of the item as laid out in the stat block.

> Caster Level (CL): An item's caster level indicates its relative power. It also determines the item's saving throw bonus, as well as range or other level-dependent aspects of the item's powers (if variable). It also determines the level that must be contended with should the item come under the effect of a dispel magic spell or similar situation.

From the PRD [Magic Item page](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/advancedMagicItems.html)

So, for your specific cases:
Celestial Armor Fly: CL 5 for 5 Minutes 1/day
Celestial Shield Feather Fall: CL 7 for Until landing or 7 rounds 1/day
Celestial Armor Overland Flight: Cl 5 for 5 hours 1/day

Comment: Note that if the text of the magic item specifies a different duration to the one the caster level would indicate, the text takes precedence.